# Modified version of Prim's algorithm with O(kn + m) time complexity

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, computer-science

Could you please help me with this problem?

Given an undirected graph *G*, connected, with weighted edges, such that the weights are integers in *[1,k]* . Write a modified version of Prim's algorithm that returns the minimum spanning tree in *O(kn+m)* time.

Note:

- *n* represents the number of vertices
- *m* represents the number of edges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the limited range of the edge length. This will help you keep a priority queue of the edges more efficiently. Keep in mind the most important step in the algorithm is to find the minimum-weight edge connecting the tree built thus far with a node not yet added to the tree. Try to use [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) as an inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my first attempt was to order the edges using bucket sort which has  _O(n+k)_ time complexity. As you suggested this should improve the performances of the priority queque in this scenario. If i'm not making any mistake, _O(kn+m)_ is given by  the deleteMin function that can be executed in _O(k)_ time instead of _O(logn)_ . Is that correct?